# Как победить заимствование в Rust

Tags: rust

Делаю утилитку на Rust, которая будет считать время работы программ. Не могу разобраться, как убрать ошибку.

Код:

```
use sysinfo::{ProcessExt, ProcessRefreshKind, System, SystemExt};
use std::collections::hash_map::HashMap;

fn main() {
    if System::IS_SUPPORTED {
        //println!( "This OS is supported!" );

        let mut watch_procs = HashMap::from([
            ( "l2.exe", 1 ),
            ( "mpv.exe", 1 ),
        ]);
        
        let mut system = System::new_all();
        loop {
            system.refresh_processes();
    
            for ( pid, process ) in system.processes() {
                let proc_name = process.name();
                if watch_procs.contains_key( proc_name ) {
                    watch_procs.insert(proc_name, watch_procs[proc_name] + 1);
                    println!("{} {} {}", pid, proc_name, watch_procs[proc_name]);
                }
            }
    
            std::thread::sleep( std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
        }
    } else {
        println!( "This OS isn't supported (yet?)." );
    }
    
}
```

Ошибка:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `system` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:16:13
   |
16 |             system.refresh_processes();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
17 |
18 |             for ( pid, process ) in system.processes() {
   |                                     ------------------ immutable borrow occurs here
19 |                 let proc_name = process.name();
20 |                 if watch_procs.contains_key( proc_name ) {
   |                    ------------------------------------- immutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `proc_uptime` due to previous error
```

Comment: Запускать код не пробовал, но если я его правильно понял, вы в своём HashMap пытаетесь хранить заимствования `&str` вместо владеющего типа `String`, что в данном случае видимо плохая идея

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Еле понял, но понял :).

Answer (score 0):

Работающее решение:

```
use sysinfo::{ProcessExt, System, SystemExt};
use std::collections::hash_map::HashMap;

fn main() {

    if System::IS_SUPPORTED {
        //println!( "This OS is supported!" );

        let mut watch_procs = HashMap::from([
            ( "l2.exe".to_string(), 1 ),
            ( "mpv.exe".to_string(), 1 ),
        ]);
        
        let mut system = System::new_all();
        loop {
            system.refresh_processes();
    
            for ( pid, process ) in system.processes() {
                let proc_name = &process.name().to_string();
                if watch_procs.contains_key( proc_name ) {
                    watch_procs.insert( proc_name.to_string(), watch_procs[proc_name] + 1);
                    println!( "{} {} {}", pid, proc_name, watch_procs[ proc_name ] );
                }
            }
    
            std::thread::sleep( std::time::Duration::from_millis( 1000 ) );
        }
    } else {
        println!( "This OS isn't supported (yet?)." );
    }
    
}
```

Comment: * `.to_string()` использует `Display` для форматирования, лучше вызывать `to_owned()`;
* Не нужно копировать строку два раза, лучше присвоить значение скопированной один раз строки переменной `proc_name` и брать ссылки в местах использования, где это нужно, а потом передать по значению в `insert`.

Comment: Это моя первая самостоятельная программа в rust после hello world. Видел to_owned(), теперь (смутно) понимаю что выгоднее, спасибо за разъяснения, буду вникать. Еще меня конечно смущает как я переношу стиль php в rust, но не нашел как заменить его. Два массива держать не хочется, а ассоциативные массивы меня зачаровали, великая штука. Тут целью было запустить программу, пусть и не оптимальным способом. Спасибо за коммент, обдумаю эти нюансы и почитаю доку. Просто чтение не откладывается, а когда понаделал ошибок, то начинаешь понимать где что не оптимально. Такие указания очень помогают.